# Is it possible to share an Excel file online with the autoopen feature (read-only by preference)?

Tags: ms-office, office-js, onedrive, excel-online

(* I have asked similar questions previously, but I still cannot get it work. I'm re-asking the question to see if there is some updates. *)

I could well create an Excel file with the autoopen feature by [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document#best-practices). The autoopen feature works in Excel for Windows. I upload the file to Excel Online, the autoopen feature still works for myself.

Then, I want to share this file online with other people (read-only by preference), the autoopen feature does NOT work for them online.

As examples, here is a document that `Anyone with the link can view`: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmAcI5jpNEmng2vYPFkfDRVMDFCP?e=F1I824. Here is a file that `Anyone with the link can edit`: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiGweD_mtcu2oRLt3dr9cgmJxpMI?e=Tf6OoZ. When users open the links in their browser, autoopen is NOT triggered.

Does anyone know if it is possible? Is it possible that anyone make and share such a document?

Comment: Autoopen works for me if the receiver of the file is already signed in. E.g. The have a document already open in Excel for the Web. I am also seeing that when I click Edit workbook for an anonymous user that Excel for the Web is unresponsive so I think that might be the bug that you are seeing. I reported it interally.

Comment: My previous tests long time ago showed the fact if the receiver has signed in had an impact. But recently I could not reproduce it well; the rules were just not very clear. I have never seen an online Office file with the autoopen feature made by your team. If you fix the bug, it will be great to see such a file... Thank you...